# Returning anonymous functions rather than lambda function

Tags: function, kotlin, lambda, functional-programming

I cannot understand why the `wrong` function is illegal in Kotlin

```
fun right1() : (String) -> String {
    return {
        when {
            it.isEmpty() -> "Empty"
            else -> it.reversed()
        }
    }
}


fun wrong() : (String) -> String {
    return fun(s: String): String {
        when {
            s.isEmpty() -> "Empty"
            else -> s.reversed()
        }
    }
}

fun right2() : (String) -> String {
    return {
        s: String -> 
        when {
            s.isEmpty() -> "Empty"
            else -> s.reversed()
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to be that I can only return lambda functions and non anonymous ones.

Sorry for the trivial question, I am a Kotlin newbye.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's examine why `right1` and `right2` are correct. Since you return a lambda and the lambda will return its last expression which is [`when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) it will work for `right1` and `right2`.

Now, let's take a look at `wrong`. The compiler will give the following error.

> A 'return' expression is required in a function with a block body.

So, all you have to do is add a `return` statement before `when`, like so:

```
fun notWrong() : (String) -> String {
    return fun(s: String): String {
        return when {
            s.isEmpty() -> "Empty"
            else -> s.reversed()
        }
    }
}
```

But there is a better way! Note, that you can take advantage of Kotlin's type inference like that:

```
fun notWrong() = { s: String -> // parameter of lambda is a String
    when { // String is inferred as return type of when expression
        s.isEmpty() -> "Empty"
        else -> s.reversed()
    }
}
```

This is less redundant and does the same thing: return a lambda which takes a `String` as parameter and returns a `String`.

Invoking the returned lambda will work like this:

```
notWrong()("Hello World")
```

The first pair of parenthesis are for the invocation of `notWrong` and the second for the invocation of the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

You can return anonymous functions. Just add `return` statement before `when` and it will work:

```
fun wrong() : (String) -> String {
    return fun(s: String): String {
        return when {
            s.isEmpty() -> "Empty"
            else -> s.reversed()
        }
    }
}
```

And you can call it something like this:

```
wrong()("string")
// or using a variable:
val v = wrong()
v("string")
```